# NodeJS-Express res.json y res.render

Tags: android, nodejs, rest, express

Estoy haciendo un cliente móvil para mi aplicación en NodeJS pero no tengo mucha experiencia haciendo un REST Web Service, y estoy intentando devolver un JSON en mi aplicación para recibirlo en la APP en Android, pero sólo devuelvo un solo tipo de archivo, el HTML o JSON pero no los 2. Que puedo hacer? Debo hacer el WebService a parte?

```
getViewIndex(req, res, next){
    //console.log(req.user.nombres);
    //console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    if(!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.redirect('/');
    else{            
        res.render('index', { //envio el html
            title: 'Bienvenido',
            user: req.user
        });
        res.json(req.user); //envio el JSON
    }
}
```

Sólo envía el primer archivo, le cambio el orden y envía siempre el primero.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Request tiene solo 1 Response. No podes hacer un request y que devuelva 2 responses de diferentes tipos... Si lo que queres es retornar el JSON solo deberías hacer la segunda, la primera esta renderizando una pagina y le estas enviando data para que el Template Engine (Ej. Handelbars) renderize un HTML con esa data que le estas pasando.

Si solo queres retornar JSON, realiza el numero 2.

Comment: entonces una API RESTful la debo hacer independiente, osea con otra ruta verdad? Gracias

Comment: una API generalmente no sirve HTML, es una API. Podes hacer un mismo server con 2 endpoints, uno para cada cosa.

Comment: @ArielRey si por lo general no sirve HTML, pero también una respuesta puede tener varios tipos re representación json, xml, incluso HTML , depende de la implementación y requerimientos

Answer (score 1):

como ya lo mencionaron por cada petición al servidor hay una sola respuesta. pero la respuesta pueden ser dos elementos por ejemplo

```
  res.json({html: "<p>Hola mundo</p>", json:{msg: "hola" });
```

Ya del lado del cliente haces lo pertinente renderizas html o manejas el json, que esto me parece mala practica o mandar que tiepo respeta necesitas json etc, yo lo que haría y pensado en una arquitectura REST usaría la cabecera [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) indicando lo que necesito text/html o application/json, el servidor responde de manera adecuada algo asi

```
const { headers: { Accept }} = req;
if(Accept === 'text/html'){
    res.render(...)
} ...
```

obviamente, por cada tipo solicitud responder adecuadamente con [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) y así, bueno es lo que haría,